# How to test samba/afp configuration remote server?

Tags: server, ssh, samba, tunnel

I am using Ubuntu as desktop and server OS. When I am logged in to the server via SSH on the terminal to change the smb/afp configuration, I can only test the configuration from the server over terminal.

Is there a way to tunnel the connection over SSH (no VPN, only one SSH port is open on the firewall) so that I also could test the connection from my Ubuntu or OS X desktop host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ssh to tunnel any port under SSH.

```
sudo ssh -L 139:localhost:139 user@server
```

Now if you try to connect to the 139 port in your computer you will be connecting to 139 in the server. Notes:

- You need to use sudo to open a priviledged port(<1024) on your computer, not nice.
- It won't work if you're already using port 139 (i.e. you are running samba on the local computer)
- You will need to use your local computer by IP (we are not tunneling nbm).

Not nice at all, but it's the best idea that I have.

Comment: OS x does not allow to connect to the localhost over afp/smb I'll try Ubuntu later